# validation on differnet fields single button click in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

Actually I do a form validation on single button click. But I have one `DropdownList` that contains two values. When `DropDownList` value changes, I show different fields and some fields are hidden. I want to do a validation on these fields, but I want to validate only currently showing fields on form not on hidden field.

Comment: Can you post your codes whatever you have written

Comment: are you hiding with client script or server script?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Using Swich case.
You have 5 fields : A,B,C,D,E
When Combo box has value =1, then A,B are showing.
When Combo box has value =2, then C,D,E are showing.

On the button click:

With combo box has value 1: Validation fields: A,B

With combo box has value 2: Validation fields: C,D,E

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using validation controls to validate your form and if you are using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList` for hiding or showing controls depending on the `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList`, then you can use the same event to remove the `ValidationGroup` from the Validation Controls, like this.

```
proteced void yourDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged (Object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yourDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Value1")
    {
        yourValidatorControl1.ValidationGroup = String.Empty;
        yourValidatorControl2.ValidationGroup = String.Empty;
        yourValidatorControl3.ValidationGroup = "yourValidationGroup";
        yourValidatorControl4.ValidationGroup = "yourValidationGroup";
        yourValidatorControl5.ValidationGroup = "yourValidationGroup";
    }
    else if (yourDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Value2")
    {

        yourValidatorControl1.ValidationGroup = "yourValidationGroup";
        yourValidatorControl2.ValidationGroup = "yourValidationGroup";
        yourValidatorControl3.ValidationGroup = String.Empty;
        yourValidatorControl4.ValidationGroup = String.Empty;
        yourValidatorControl5.ValidationGroup = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

If this is not the case then post some code, how you are validating and making your controls visible/hidden.

Comment: Hi, this code work for server side, i want to it on client side.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some of your code? That will help me provide you some client side code.